# Is it possible to use a script to block adware recursive links in a browser window?

Tags: security, scripting, server-side

There are client-side solutions for nasty adware and their recursive links, but is it possible to use a script in the html to prevent the links from displaying in a user's browser who has adware on their machine and is visiting my web site?

I am NOT a programmer. I am designer, and I know just enough to create problems that send me to forums like this.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it. Malware like that injects links and creates popups by manipulating the internals of the browser.